How to load vuetify/lib from CDN to achieve minimal sized app
I'm serving a website from a $1 ESP32 which has very little free flash so I need to make it as tiny as possible. Loading all of my packages from a CDN is the best way to achieve this. My site is also gziped.
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue', 'vue-router', 'pinia', 'vuetify', 'webfontloader', 'core-js', 'vuetify/styles'],
      output: {
        paths: {
          'vue-router': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@4.5.0/dist/vue-router.global.min.js',
          vue: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.5.13/dist/vue.global.min.js',
          pinia: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pinia@2.3.0/dist/pinia.iife.min.js',
          vuetify: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.7.6/dist/vuetify.min.js',
          'vuetify/styles': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.7.6/dist/vuetify.min.css',
          webfontloader: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/webfontloader@1.6.28/webfontloader.min.js',
          'core-js': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/core-js@3.39.0/proposals/reflect-metadata.min.js',
        }
      }
    }
  },

When I analyze the map of my app 'vuetify/lib' is still getting copied into it. How do I convince vite to load 'vuetify/lib' from the CDN? I tried making a rollupOptions external entry for 'vuetify/lib' and that didn't change anything.


You need to make sure that imports contain only from 'vuetify' and not from 'vuetify/...'

vite-plugin-vuetify is doing it, import { generateImports, Options } from '@vuetify/loader-shared'   When I remove vite-plugin-vuetify it doesn't include vuetify/lib anymore.
